# How to create a simple increment button in Ruby on Rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've started RoR recently by doing rails for zombies tutorial, and now i'd like to start creating little apps but I'm stuck at the very beginning. I only want to have a button that adds 1 to a variable.

Here is the best I have :

*routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "counter#index"
end
```

*counter_controller.rb*

```
class CounterController < ActionController::Base

  def index
    if @clicks != nil
      @clicks = @clicks + 1
    else
      @clicks = 0
    end
  end

end
```

*index.html.erb*

```
<%= button_to "Add", root_path, method: :get %>
<%= @clicks %>
```

What am I missing here ? 
Thanks

Comment: You're never initializing `@clicks` and is therefore always set to `0`. Also you really should have a separate action to handle the post request, and other one for showing the page.

Comment: I added the initialize function in my controller, but it's called every time I click on the button, because my page is reloading. I can't find a button which doesnt reload the page on the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a complicated task if you only start out as a progammer.

You're almost there. You have a serverside variable now to represent the value you want to be increasing.

To actually save the value of the button you need to store it somewhere. This is because every time a request is made to rails, the application acts like it doesn't know anything. It's stateless. Storing the value can be either in a persistent storage like a database or temporary storage like a [session](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/).

To store the click value temporary you could use:

```
def index
    if session[:clicks] != nil
      session[:clicks] = session[:clicks] + 1
    else
      session[:clicks] = 0
    end
  end
```

To solve this problem properly, you could:

- Make a model and controller for 'Click' with `rails generate scaffold Click`
- Create the database and run the migrations
- In the template add `<%= link_to "Increase count", clicks_path, remote: true, method: :create %>`. This should fire a POST on /clicks every time the button is pressed.
- Modify the countercontroller#index method to return the amount of clicks. You can replace all the code in the method with:

---

```
def index
   @clicks = Click.all.count
end
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's working. But I assume it's not the best way to do this ? Since the page is reloading every time I press the button

Comment: If you want to prevent a page reload, you should look into using AJAX
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: @Raytho updated my answer to support AJAX and store the value in a correct way.